# 404 error because of AJAX?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, .htaccess

Alright, I have no idea how to put this question but I'm trying to keep it short and understandable.
So I've been following [this](http://www.phpclasses.org/blog/package/3213/post/1-Tutorial-on-Creating-an-AJAX-based-Chat-system-in-PHP.html) tutorial. (for the full code)

I've modified the code a bit to my liking but I get this error

```
GET http://sample.com/refresh.php/?lastTimeID=0 404 (Not Found)
```

(This is from browser developer console)
This is the code where it goes wrong, I think..

```
var lastTimeID = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btnSend').click( function() {
    sendChatText();
    $('#chatInput').val("");
  });
  startChat();
});

function startChat(){
  setInterval( function() { getChatText(); }, 2000);
}

function getChatText() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/refresh.php?lastTimeID=" + lastTimeID
  }).done( function( data )
  {
    var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
    var jsonLength = jsonData.results.length;
    var html = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < jsonLength; i++) {
      var result = jsonData.results[i];
      html += '<div>(' + result.chattime + ') <b>' + result.usrname +'</b>: ' + result.chattext + '</div>';
      lastTimeID = result.id;
    }
    $('#view_ajax').append(html);
  });
}

function sendChatText(){
  var chatInput = $('#chatInput').val();
  if(chatInput != ""){
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "/submit.php?chattext=" + encodeURIComponent( chatInput )
    });
  }
}
```

This is what I'm confused about; it shows http://sample.com/refresh.php/?lastTimeID=0
But where does it get the "/" after refresh.php? Is this supposed to happen? Something to do with `.htaccess`?

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /admin/$1/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /admin/index.php/$1 [L]
```

How do I fix this error?
Just like I said, I have no clue on how to ask this correctly. 
And another little question; is it appropriate to look at the browser developer console? 

If you need more information, feel free to ask!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you got any configured htaccess? What's its content?

Comment: 404 failure nothing to do with variable pass(?lastTimeID=0). have you try to load   http://sample.com/refresh.php/?lastTimeID=0 direct from url bar if it's also produce 404 error. and also share .htaccess code if it's installed

Comment: @YPS Thanks for the fast response. If I load up  sample.com/refresh.php/?lastTimeID=0 it gave me a 404 error. And I'll add the .htaccess

Comment: I'd guess your htaccess does mess it up, just now (chrome) i wrote `$.ajax({type: "GET", url: "/refresh.php?lastTimeID=2"}).done(function(){ console.log(arguments);});` in the console and it gives me "GET http://stackoverflow.com/refresh.php?lastTimeID=2&_=1441180776327 404 (Not Found)" ;) Try commenting out rules 1 by one..?

Comment: `GET http://sample.com/refresh.php?lastTimeID=0 ` remove \ after refresh.php

Comment: @EricG Alright I have messed with the .htaccess file and it worked! Well, so far...  It now gives me the error it can't find  sample.com/refresh.php?lastTimeID=0 any suggestions on this? Thanks!

Comment: @EricG Alright I fixed this! Thank you very much!

Comment: Excellent glad to be of help! ^_^ PS I think you should post your solution for other people ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after the help of EricG, I disabled the whole .htaccess which caused the problem, which means that there is a line in there you should try to comment one by one. I didn't need to use the .htaccess. But you should consider checking your .htaccess (or disabling it if not used)

Credits to EricG and all others who tried to help me out!

Comment: Can't estimate the use or impact of removing .htaccess though :) Glad I could be of help!

Answer (score 0):

Add data in you ajax request, like so:

```
type: "GET",
url: "/refresh.php",
data: {  
  lastTimeID:lastTimeID
},
```

... this will leave your function looking like this:

Replace full function.

```
function getChatText() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://sample.com/refresh.php",
    data: {  
      lastTimeID:lastTimeID
    },
  }).done( function( data )
  {
    var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
    var jsonLength = jsonData.results.length;
    var html = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < jsonLength; i++) {
      var result = jsonData.results[i];
      html += '<div>(' + result.chattime + ') <b>' + result.usrname +'</b>: ' + result.chattext + '</div>';
      lastTimeID = result.id;
    }
    $('#view_ajax').append(html);
  });
}
```

Comment: In future, please *edit* your answer to add additional information, as opposed to posting multiple answers.